# Можно ли сделать из Brackets полноценную IDE c LivePreview для страниц с расширением PHP?

Tags: php, brackets

1. Можно ли через Brackets устанавливать связь с БД и вытаскивать из нее данные при помощи PHP?
2. Можно ли через Brackets запускать LivePreview для страниц с расширением PHP?

   Грубо говоря мне нужно сделать из Brackets PHPStorm. Просто PHPStorm имеет кучу недостатков (ИМХО): неудобный дизайн; отсутствует функция быстрого редактирования кода(!!!); LivePreview изменяется не динамически; Огромное количество расширений в свободном доступе, которые упрощают работу; я привык работать в Brackets.

Comment: "отсутствует функция быстрого редактирования кода" --- что под этим подразумевается?  "LivePreview изменяется не динамически" --- вы просто не умеете его готовить)

Comment: @СергейМишин если вы пользовались Brackets, то возможно вы знакомы с функцией "Быстрое редактирование кода", она из себя представляет следующее: при клике на класс какого-то элемента и нажатии определенного сочетания клавиш, на той же странице появляется код CSS для этого класса, который вы можете отредактировать прямо там и после закрыть.
Если вы знаете как подключить эту же функцию или ее аналог в PHPStorm, пожалуйста, подскажите как!